# VMWare Workstation Stretch Guest disabled

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-14.04

I have Windows 8.1 Pro, in which VMWare Workstation 10.03 is installed. The guest system I use there is Ubuntu 14.04. VMWare tools are installed on the Guest System and I ofen use shared folders with no problems.

The problem I have is that the resolution of my screen is so high that it's impossible to work with full resolution. So I want to use the option Stretch Guest in the virtual machine, so that I could have items visible. But... the Stretch Guest option is disabled (grayed out).

Why is it disabled? What should I do to enable it?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out autosize: http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-09/03831637142672175214.jpg

Comment: @UltraDEVV Autofit changes the resolution, and I don't want to change the resolution. I just want to stretch the selected resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The menu item View>Autosize>Stretch Guest is only enabled in full-screen mode (circa Workstation 12.5).

Tangent: You can set "stretch" as default for full-screen mode with the "Stretch Guest" radio button in Edit>Preferences>Displays.